# Regular expression preg_match_all test to capture more than two new lines is failing

Tags: php, regex

I have a regular expression - /\r\n|\r|\n{3,}/g - that works in Javascript to capture an instance where a user has entered 3+ line breaks in a row. I then take that instance and convert it back to 2 line breaks.

Now, I am trying to do my server-side validation in PHP and, in the absence of being able to use the 'g' flag, I gather I need to use preg_match_all(). However, I can't seem to get preg_match_all( "/\r\n|\r|\n{3,}/", $value) to return 0 if there are no instances of three new line breaks in a row - for some reason, it seems to be ignoring the {3,} part of the regex.

The test text ($value) I am passing in for validation via a text area input is:

```
Test

Test
```

At most, it has two new lines in a row so it should return 0 matches - this is correctly reflected in the Javascript results on the client side. Permutations of the preg_match_all I have tried are:

```
preg_match_all( "/\r\n|\r|\n{3,}/", $value); -> 2 matches
preg_match_all( "/(\r\n|\r|\n{3,})/", $value); -> 2 matches
preg_match_all( "/(\r\n|\r|\n){3,}/", $value); -> 1 match
preg_match_all( "/[(\r\n|\r|\n)]{3,}/", $value); -> 1 match
preg_match_all( "/([(\r\n|\r|\n)]{3,})/", $value); -> 1 match
preg_match_all( "/(\r\n|\r|\n{3,})+/", $value); -> 1 match
```

My original regex - /\r\n|\r|\n{3,}/g - works with the test on http://www.regexr.com/ (i.e. it has no matches on the above test text). It also works when I run it as follows:

```
preg_match_all( "/\r\n|\r|\n{3,}/", "Test\n\nTest"); -> 0 matches
preg_match_all( "/\r\n|\r|\n{3,}/", "Test\n\n\nTest"); -> 1 match
preg_match_all( "/\r\n|\r|\n{3,}/", "Test\n\n\nTest\n\nTest\n\n\nTest"); -> 2 matches
```

I am not really sure how form submission could be affecting the results of the preg_match_all test. It's probably something very simple I am missing - if anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the string you're running `preg_match_all()` against to see what characters it actually has?

Comment: I have var_dump()ed it between <pre> tags and get the following result: string(12) "Test

Test" You can't see it in this comment but there are visually two line breaks there on the page when it outputs. Also, the fact that it's a 12 char string seems to imply it's actually "Test\n\nTest" - I think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to match the '\r` as a standalone line break, you'd need to make
it an atomic group, so the engine doesn't try to match invalid pieces.

This seems to work -

`(?>\r?\n|\r){3,}`

And for your test case

```
Test

Test
```

it won't find 3 valid line breaks.

Comment: This also works! I can't replicate a test for standalone '\r's (which I gather were used as pre OSX line breaks?) but it sounds like yours incorporates that legacy possibility which is what I was trying to add on to Ioannis' solution. I'm not sure I totally understand what the first part of the regex '?>' means in terms of evaluation - is it saying to match \r or \n singly first and then \r\n?

Comment: The `(?>..)` is an _atomic_ group construct. It protects its _contents_ from the engine backtracking into it, like it does when it tries to match the alternations. If you give the engine an option via alternation to match the entire outcome, it will take it via backtracking. Alternations have priority from left to right, but like it _will_ backtrack (ie. split a valid line break) if it has to. The _atomic_ construct prevents that.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for taking the time to respond and explain, @sln. Accepting your answer for including the possibility of standalone '\r's. Thanks again!

Comment: @mpmurph - No problem. Good luck  !

Answer (score 1):

Since you are searching for newlines you must search either for /r (Mac), /n (Unix) or /r/n (Windows) - and only one of those 3 times or more - and not for a mix of those.

So the pattern should be:

```
/(\r\n){3,}|(\n{3,})|(\r{3,})/
```

And some test code:

```
$pattern = "/(\r\n){3,}|(\n{3,})|(\r{3,})/";
$a = preg_match_all( "{$pattern}", "Test\r\n\r\n\r\nTest");
assert($a===1);

$a = preg_match_all( "{$pattern}", "Test\n\n\nTest");
assert($a===1);

$a = preg_match_all( "{$pattern}", "Test\r\r\rTest");
assert($a===1);

$a = preg_match_all( "{$pattern}", "Test\r\n\r\nTest");
assert($a===0);
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much!! I thought I was testing for it with the leading \r\n but it seems it must be grouped. For some reason though, if I add a \r to your expression - /((\r\n)|\n|\r){3,}/ - the test doesn't work again. Would you mind walking me through why that would be the case?

Comment: I have (radically) updated my answer - see if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you, Ioannis! I just saw this after accepting @sln's answer for including a test for '\r' too. His answer is: (?>\r?\n|\r){3,} I gather the atomic group construct helps prevent backtracking and the possibility of splitting valid line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this `preg_match_all("/\r?\n|\r){3,}/", $value);`
It means that `\r\n` or `\n`, or \r (which are in brackets) should appear three or more times.

Most of yours tries match `\r\n`, or `\r`, or tree times `\n`

Comment: That's the third permutation I tried (see above) - it puzzlingly returns one match to the form submission.

Comment: Then, I'm pretty sure that the issue is in the `$value` string because `"Test Test"` contains only 10 characters. I think another two may be line breaks at the end of it.

Comment: Regex engines will try to match that even if it has to divide up invalid line breaks. So, `(\r\n|\r|\n){3,}` matches 0x0d0x0a0x0d0x0a which is only 2 valid line breaks.

Comment: I see, you are right. @mpmurph, I have updated regexp to handle this case correctly.